# Laravel notification won't send

Tags: php, laravel

I try to send notification to Twitter when new post created but I'm getting:

```
Couldn't post Notification. Response: Bad Authentication data.
```

## Codes

**Notification class**

```
use NotificationChannels\Twitter\TwitterChannel;
use NotificationChannels\Twitter\TwitterStatusUpdate;
use App\Post;

class PostPublished extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [TwitterChannel::class, TelegramChannel::class];
    }

    public function toTwitter($post)
    {
        $title = $post->title;
        $slug = $post->slug;
        $image = $post->image;
        return new TwitterStatusUpdate($title .' https://domain.co/blog/'. $slug, [$image]);
    }
```

**Post controller**

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\PostPublished;

$post->save();
$post->notify(new \App\Notifications\PostPublished($post));
```

**Post model**

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Notifiable;
```

## Question

1. Why I'm getting this error?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: Your API keys in your `.env` file are wrong

Comment: @Ohgodwhy just now i created new app and this is how i used them in `env` file  https://preview.ibb.co/iwyOon/dddd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

All I needed to do was :

```
php artisan config:cach
composer dump-autoload
```

now it's working like charm.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely something wrong with your configuration or your tokens. It looks to me as if something is not set up properly. In your `config/services.php` file do you have the following?

```
'twitter' => [
    'consumer_key'    => env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'),
    'consumer_secret' => env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'),
    'access_token'    => env('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
    'access_secret'   => env('TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET')
]
```

Please check to ensure all of these are set correctly using tinker. In the terminal type `php artisan tinker` and then check each of the following one line at a time:

```
env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'),
env('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'),
env('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
env('TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET')
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i do have those in my services and env file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186831/laravel-notification-wont-send#comment87390589_50186831. but also I'll double check by your way as well and let you know

Comment: Ok, I checked with tinker and this is what i got: https://ibb.co/jWvv3n | 
https://ibb.co/bFYhin

Comment: now it's working :) all I needed was to clear my config cache and dump my composer data, thanks

Comment: glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Note it can be type error in any part of .env file, not only twitter access tokens and key, for example:

```
APP_NAME=Name of your App
```

instead of:

```
APP_NAME="Name of your App"
```